# Inserting values into database table using static method when button is clicked

Tags: java, sql

I'm working on a project that is used to gather customer information and store it into a table called "BOOKINGS" The table has columns "CUSTOMERNAME","HOLIDAYNAME", "MAGICIAN", and "TIMESTAMP"

I have a class called "DatabaseConnection" that establishes a connection to the database that has the bookings table. This class has functioned as expected in other areas of the project. Within the class I have a static method called "addBooking"

I have a GUI class (using Netbeans GUI generator) that has an actionperformed method. Here is the code for the actionperformed method and the addBooking method...

```
private void bookButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


    String customerName = customerNameText.getText();
    String magician = (String)magicianCombo.getSelectedItem();
    String holiday = (String)holidayCombo.getSelectedItem();

    customerNameText.setText(null);

    try {
        DatabaseConnection.addBooking(customerName, holiday, magician);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI1Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I didn't send any information for timestamp because I haven't figured that part out just yet. Here is the code for the addBooking method in the DatabaseConnection class.

```
public static void addBooking(String name, String holiday, String employee) throws SQLException { 
    stmt.execute("INSERT INTO BOOKINGS (CUSTOMERNAME, HOLIDAYNAME, MAGICIAN) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+holiday+"','"+employee+"')");
}
```

Clicking the button is supposed to get information from a textbox (Customer name), information from a combo box (holiday) and information from another combo box (employee). I can't figure out why it isn't working, but whenever the button is clicked the program freezes for about 10-15 seconds and then continues, but no information is entered in the table. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Added code for the rest of DatabaseConnection class

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MagicianAgent";
String username = "java";
String password = "java";

static Connection con = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
static Statement stmt;

DatabaseConnection() { 
    try { 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    }
    catch(SQLException err) { 
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
}

public ResultSet getRS(String sql) { 
    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    }
    catch(SQLException err) { 
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
    return rs;
}
```

EDIT 2: This is some code I have in the main method.

```
    Holiday holidayList = new Holiday();
    Magician magicianNames = new Magician();
    arrays = magicianNames.getMagicianNames();
    for(int e = 0; e < arrays.size(); e++ ) { 
        magicianCombo.addItem(arrays.get(e));
    }
    arrays = holidayList.getHolidayList();
    for(int e = 0; e < arrays.size(); e++) { 
        holidayCombo.addItem(arrays.get(e));
    }
```

In the Holiday and Magician constructors, they access the database through DatabaseConnection and store the values of holiday names and magician names in an ArrayList. Then the ArrayList items are added to the combo box until the end of the ArrayList is reached. I'm not sure if this would change the behavior of anything, but I thought I should add it.

Comment: show us more about `DatabaseConnection`

Comment: Aside from anything else, your `addBooking` method should be fixed to use parameterized SQL. Get in the habit of that *now* before you work on any real code where a SQL Injection Attack can be business-threatening...

Comment: Typically a statement is prepared with the query and then executed - what is `stmt`? Also, your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection): if you enter `','',''); DROP TABLE BOOKINGS --` in the customerName field, ....

Comment: You're performing database operations on the EDT, that is why the GUI freezes, also, you don't seem to create or close the `stmt` anywhere in the code that you've posted.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, i'll look into that.

Comment: @jtomaszk I added more information.

Comment: try to create new DatabaseConnection and convert addBooking to non static

Comment: @jtomaszk I tried doing that in the GUI class, but for some reason it messed up other parts of the database.

Comment: so maybe try to call `con.commit()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't pre-create the `Statement` object, and use `PrepareStatement` to guard against SQL syntax errors and [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

So, your code should be:

```
public static void addBooking(String name, String holiday, String employee) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKINGS (CUSTOMERNAME, HOLIDAYNAME, MAGICIAN) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.setString(2, holiday);
        stmt.setString(3, employee);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using the PreparedStatement but it still freezes and doesn't update the database. I added some more information. Not sure if it will help or not.

Comment: @Chris That comment makes no sense to me. You have showed no `main` method. You have showed no use of `PrepareStatement`. "not working" is a useless comment. Be specific. Or rather, create a new question. One question per question, please.

Comment: @Chris And read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I added an edit in my question, it's the code that I have within the main method. I didn't show the use of the PreparedStatement because it is exactly the same code as what you have in your reply. I told you the issue was that it freezes and doesn't update the database. The question I am asking is still the same question.

Comment: @Chris You error handling sucks. Since this is a GUI program, what do you think the following statement does `System.out.println(err.getMessage());`? It prints nowhere, then ignores the error and continues. If you could actually see the error, you'd probably find that the database connection is not working because there is no Derby database at localhost:1527, and your "freeze" is the connection timeout. **Don't ignore errors!!!!** Sure, log them, but don't just continue as if nothing bad happened.

Comment: That prints out to the console. I can see the error if there is one, and no error is printing. It does connect to the database. I fill the combo boxes with information from the database and that works just fine.